# POST to server with encodeURIComponent containing >< characters causing a 301 redirect

Tags: javascript, wordpress, apache, post, redirect

I'm POSTing an HTML string to an Apache server with the receiving function simply writing the string to a database.  There's nothing big or clever about it and it works on every other implementation.

I am encodeURIComponent-ing the string before POST and the server is returning a 301 redirect and diverting to a GET request on a non-www version of the domain.  There's nothing in htaccess beyond a standard Wordpress configuration. In any case, this is simply a text string.  I have also replace the function on the server with simply an exit() to remove that from the equation.

I use the same mechanism to post numerous other data to this server via the same target function without a problem.

I've discovered the problem is sending the characters >< together - as it's sending HTML these occur a lot.

So I'm sending via: encodeURIComponent("<span class='teststring'><span>")

which POSTS.. action=updatemenu&mstring=%3Cspan%20class%3D'teststring'%3E%3Cspan%3E

and returns.. POST http://www.DOMAINREMOVED.co.uk/twdc/CMS/TellMe.php  301 Moved Permanently  301ms
followed by.. 
GET http://DOMAINREMOVED.co.uk/twdc/CMS/TellMe.php 301 Moved Permanently 108ms

If I remove either the > or < from the >< pattern it works fine! Reducing the above encodedURI string to just >< results in the same error.

I am at a complete loss.  Anyone come across this before or have any ideas?  I guess ultimately I can replace the string in question with something safe but that has implications as all user input would have to be encoded/decoded just in case. Surely this shouldn't be necessary?

I just tried switching out all the >< in the POST string with **replace(/%3E%3C/g,"~~")** on the encodeURIComponent result and it's passed to the server without the redirect/error.

### Edit 00:00 19th July..

I've noticed with the >< in POST, this is the response header.  The x-pingback doesn't appear in the response header without the offending characters.

```
 
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 18 Jul 2013 22:57:07 GMT
Expires Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Location    http://*domain*.co.uk/twdc/CMS/TellMe.php
Pragma          no-cache
Server          Apache
X-Pingback  http://*domain*.co.uk/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.17
```

I guess this is WordPress-related. Can anyone shed any light on this?

To be clear the current site is Wordpress-based; the replacement is not but they are coexisting during the build of the new one.

Comment: anything in the error logs?

Comment: no.. absolutely nothing, Matthew..

Comment: can we see the function that handles this request? If it's in asp.net MVC there are a few things that i can think of that would cause this.

Comment: It's PHP but I've reduced it to simply echo "success"; to remove it as a potential cause of the issue.

Comment: is it a standalone php file or is it using a framework like CakePHP or Laravel?

Comment: standalone php. I don't think it's reaching the php file though.

Comment: I'm sending the POST with this header in case it's relevant: channel.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the issue with Wordpress and POSTing HTML characters is however I have found that if I encode the data I want to send as a JSON object I get no objection from the server.

I presume that stops whatever function wordpress uses from parsing the HTML in some way.. I would still like to know the explanation though!